# SP to return x number of records with partition on unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, partition

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will return 8 records, that should all be partitioned by a field to be unique, unless there are not enough unique values. It must return 8 records.

Sample data:

| fld1 | fld2 | fld3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 198 | 1480 |
| 2 | 200 | 1373 |
| 3 | 203 | 220 |
| 4 | 205 | 205 |
| 5 | 207 | 16678 |
| 6 | 212 | 205 |
| 7 | 214 | 220 |
| 8 | 221 | 16678 |
| 9 | 222 | 108 |
| 10 | 223 | 205 |

Currently, I have this for the stored procedure (missing a few lines) which works to return 8 records, as long as there are 8 unique values in fld3. The piece I'm stuck on is how to return 8 records in there are only 7 unique values in fld3 as in the data above. I would want 6 unique values in fld 3 and then 2 records that would have the same values in fld 3 but also not one of the previously chosen 6 records. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Get8Records
  --passing in variables here
AS
BEGIN TRY
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;
  SELECT TOP 8 fld1, fld2, fld3
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT fld1,
                    fld2,
                    fld3,
                    row_number() OVER (partition by fld3 order by fld1) AS rn
    FROM tblName
    GROUP BY fld1, fld2, fld3
        ) t WHERE rn <= 1'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  --error hander
END CATCH
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL?

Comment: And if there are only 7 unique values, what are the 8 rows you are expecting? Please show your desired results.

Comment: the full sp is actually building some filtering in that i didn't show in the question so i'm building it with dynamic sql. As far as the question of returning 8 rows when there are 7 unique values is that it's a requirement. Our lab staff wants to select 8 samples every so of from new specimens that have been tested in a time period. Generally, there will always be more than 8 unique values in fld3, but that may not always be the case and they have to test 8.

Comment: 1) Given you have managed to simplify the scenario - well done - why not just show us the static SQL? Easier for all. 2) You still have to define to us what the 8th row should look like - else how would we know to write a query?

Comment: Fair enough, made some edits. The 8th row would have a duplicate value in fld 3 but not one of the previously chosen records.

Comment: What if there are more than 8 unique values?

Comment: Then it should get 8 unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` function to order your rows a bit like your were doing, but combine with `TOP 8`.

You can modify the row number ordering to meet any other requirements you might have.

```
declare @MyTable table (fld1 int, fld2 int, fld3 int);

insert into @MyTable (fld1, fld2 ,fld3)
values
(1, 198, 1480),
(2, 200, 1373),
(3, 203, 220),
(4, 205, 205),
(5, 207, 16678),
(6, 212, 205),
(7, 214, 220),
(8, 221, 16678),
(9, 222, 108),
(10, 223, 205);

select top 8 *
from @MyTable
order by row_number() over (partition by fld3 order by fld2) asc;
```

Returns:

| fld1 | fld2 | fld3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 205 | 205 |
| 9 | 222 | 108 |
| 3 | 203 | 220 |
| 5 | 207 | 16678 |
| 1 | 198 | 1480 |
| 2 | 200 | 1373 |
| 6 | 212 | 205 |
| 7 | 214 | 220 |

Comment: You can actually put `ROW_NUMBER` directly in the `ORDER BY` weirdly

Comment: @Charlieface true I keep forgetting that :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to order by `fld1` and `fld2` first before `fld3`, then take the top 8 rows.

I don't know whether you still need the `GROUP BY`, so I've left it in.

```
SELECT TOP (8)
  fld1,
  fld2,
  fld3
FROM tblName
GROUP BY
  fld1,
  fld2,
  fld3
ORDER BY
  fld1,
  fld2,
  fld3;
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't return all the unique values first i.e. when I ran it I didn't get fld3=108.

Comment: Might have misunderstood the question, it was a little unclear